# VSCode make multiple class

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to create multiple classes at the same time in CSS Using VSCode like the Emmet plugin in HTML?

```
.class-1 {}
.class-2 {}
...
.class-10 {}
```

Comment: Check out the VSCode multi cursor: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor

Comment: For more advanced editing there are extensions such as Increment Selection or VSCode Progressive Increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, if you want full Emmet capabilities in VSCode, use the [Emmet extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FallenMax.mithril-emmet).